# opening and saving files with java using Runtime commands

Tags: java, excel

I have an excel file which gets realtime data from lot' s of different servers with excel macros and updates it' s cell values automatically.

I want my java code to open this excel file. After it gets all of it' s cell values i want
to save this file to the local disk and a java program will read the file.

I have already implemented the open file method with java which is

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\excelmacros\\xxxxxx.xls");
```

Question is how can I save opened file after all of the cells are filled and after saving the file i want to close opened file and i also want not to let others to close the file except my java program.

Comment: If you want to do any *excel operations*, then use Apache POI or JXL, else normal FileIO operations would suffice.

Comment: Use Apache POI, OpenOffice.org, Zoho.. Use one of these Open source. and Zoho Remote API is Open Source. and Zoho Data API is not an open source..

Comment: You need to run a program with an API available to Java.